# Pug template loading error '<' unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pug, parcel

I'm trying to load a React-jsx file using my PUG template. But I'm getting

```
 Unexpected token '<'
```

when I look into the browser console. Here is my code. I'm using Parcel.

```
doctype html
head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  title Pearson Launch
  base(href='/launch-ui')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
  link(rel='shortcut icon' href='./lib/favicon.ico')
script(type='application/javascript' src='jsx/main.jsx')
```

Im new to Pug Template related development. Can you please explain is this not possible?

Comment: Should the script tag be indented one level to be a child of the `<head>` element?

Comment: No. I wanted to place the script tag below the body tag. I'm suspecting that my main.jsx contains import statements. Here what I am trying to do is to replace Parcel entry point index.html with index.pug because I want to pass some information dynamically to my react app went It is loading. With index.html it is working perfectly. Once I replace index.html with index.pug I got this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue was incorrect file path. I just created a virtual path as follow.

```
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And in my pug template, I just used script tag this way.

```
script( src='javascripts/jsx/main.jsx')
```

Now my file is properly loading. Since pug is a server-side rendering I can expect it the way it behaves in the browser.
But there is another issue which is,

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I will look into this and I think this is the answer to this issue.